# Batch file for loop

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am writing a batch file to run on Windows server 2008 R2, it has a `for` loop in it and no matter how many tutorials I read online and try, it won't run the for loop.

```
echo "Starting blur detection..."
if not exist %root%\output mkdir output
set tempnum = dir root | find /i "file"
set num = tempnum-5
for /l %idx in (0, 1, num) do (
   %root%\blurDetection.exe %root%\%img%__%idx%.tif %root%\output
   echo "blurDetection" %idx " of " %num )
```

Windows powershell says "idx was unexpected at this time."
Any suggestions?

EDIT: Actually I think this line is causing the problem, I don't think it is getting and integer value in return.

```
set tempnum = dir root | find /i "file"
```

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking, but it's a huge misconception that NT scripting (`.cmd`) has got anything to do with DOS batch, except for some common rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(added after initial post) Oh and I missed the biggest issue. Which is indeed this line:

```
set tempnum = dir root | find /i "file"
```

You mean to capture the output of `dir`, right? This can, AFAIK only be done inside `for`, unless you can live with outputting into a file and using that as input later.

Syntax is in such a case:

```
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
```

**Note:** those are *not* backticks.

Best explanations for NT scripting `for`: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php

**One more note:** since you appear to rely on the file name as some number, I suspect that `dir /b` would be the better choice. Plain `dir` will also output date and file size etc ...

---

IIRC names of `for` variables cannot have more than one letter. Also, inside script files (as apposed to the command line) those variables look like this:

```
%%i
```

Besides, the

```
set num=tempnum-5
```

should probably be

```
set /a num=%tempnum%-5
```

Another question about `find` is whether you meant to use  `findstr`. Too little context, but `findstr` seems more natural.

From `for /?`:

```
FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.

To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.
```

Note in particular these two statements:

- **`%variable`  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.**
- **To use the `FOR` command in a batch program, specify `%%variable` instead of `%variable`.**

Another peculiar feature of for loops is that you can split your input and tokens will get assigned to variables in alphabetical order. So inside a `for %a ...` tokens would get assigned to `%a`, `%b` and so forth ...set tempnum = dir root | find /i "file"

Comment: Thanks, now it gets through the for loop. The problem is it only goes through once. When ever I echo num, it just says "%num" so I don't think it is getting a number back from that find. The original purpose of the find was to non-recursively count the files in the root folder. If I could count the number of .tif files in the folder that would be a lot better though.

Comment: Problem here is that there are "normal" variables such as `%num%` (notice the "closing" percentage sign) and special variables such as those in `for` loops which are akin to special variables that store the parameters of subs or scripts (i.e. `%1`, `%2` ...). Normal variables require this for expansion: %VARNAME% ... instead of 'only' %VARNAME. Special variables are fine with one leading percentage sign for parameters (always) and `for` variables on the command line and two for `for` variables in scripts.

Comment: @keepitreall89: use `dir /b`, btw

Comment: Note that there is rarely a need to use `dir` inside a `for`, unless you need sorting or other options only `dir` can provide. `for` can iterate over variables just fine and without the hassle that `dir` creates in that case. E.g. file names with Unicode will not round-trip correctly with default settings, and unless you take care of the tokenizing, file names with spaces pose a problem too.

Comment: Oh, re `dir /b` again: This will not work as they rely on the normal `dir` output. See my answer once it appears (hopefully within the next half hour or so).

Comment: @Joey: in your first comment you probably mean to say "can iterate over files/folders just fine". Yes it can, but it also used to have caveats in earlier `cmd.exe` versions. But can you please explain why `dir /b` would not work? I could not find that in your answer. Also, from the existing code, Unicode should not be a problem (and Unicode is anyway a whole new problem space with NT scripts).

Comment: Usually you iterate over `dir /b` output since you want to do something with the file names or files. If you didn't alter the defaults of the console window (i.e. Raster fonts) and have file names with Unicode names which *don't* fit into the OEM codepage, then the result is messy, as your variable then holds the name *converted into the OEM codepage*. With a normal `for` the variable holds the actual file name and you can pass it around, even with Raster fonts. I commented a bit early here as it doesn't actually matter, as they don't need the file names where you suggested `dir /b` ...

Comment: ... it was just a fancy way of figuring out the number of files (hence the `dir | findstr "file"` although they forgot that they were interested only in the first token of that line). Generally, though, I like writing batch files that are robust when moved around systems with possibly different locales, settings or whatnot. This includes things like avoiding Unicode breakage, space breakage, assuming the cwd to be writable, etc. Maybe it is a futile quest, indeed. The main reason I wrote my answer was that I found a few issues you missed and wanted to properly explain every mistake they made.

Comment: Another note: I suggested getting the number of files via a loop (which probably is slower than the `dir` way, but more robust). I'm not terribly sure which is the right thing there. I don't feel well about the loop, but less so about the reliance on a particular OS language. My suggested final batch simply dropped the progress report in favor of saving one loop. It's probably up to the asker to decide whether that's what they want or not.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, at first glance I can see <s>five</s> <s>six</s> seven (and a half) glaring errors in here:

#### 1. Quotes around arguments to `echo`.

`echo` is a shell built-in and those had their syntax quite fixed 25 years ago in DOS and CP/M. `echo` simply prints whatever comes after it until the end of the command (which could be things like a line break, `)`, `&`, `|` , etc.), so what you want here is:

```
echo Starting blur detection ...
```

and

```
echo blurDetection %i of %num%
```

#### 2. Spaces around the equals sign in `set`.

`set`, like `echo` is a shell built-in. Its syntax is also a bit awkward (although you have the same issue on some Unix shells as well). The point here is that *everything* between `set` and the equals sign is the variable name, everything after it is the value. In this case this means that your variable name *ends with a space* and the value *starts with a space*. Therefore, whatever you do, never put spaces around the equals sign. The language of the command processor is not very forgiving on whitespaces unlike many other programming languages. Therefore:

```
set foo=bar
```

and not

```
set foo = bar
```

otherwise you will never find a variable named `foo`, because you'd need to use `%foo %` (note the space in there).

#### 3. `set` doesn't do arithmetic unless you tell it to.

`set` does not calculate anything unless you explicitly tell it to. This is done with `set /a`:

> The `/A` switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign is a numerical expression that is evaluated.

Therefore you need

```
set /a num=tempnum - 5
```

With `/a` the `%` around variable names can be omitted on the right side which makes the code a little clearer, usually.

#### 4. `set` only sets values, it doesn't execute any code.

In

```
set tempnum=dir root | find /i "file"
```

you apparently try to set a variable based on the *output* of some command. This cannot work, as this essentially just sets `tempnum` to `dir root` and sends the output of that command (there is none) to `find` because of the pipe. I'm not quite sure what this is supposed to do, but I'm guessing you're counting files.

Generally, you shouldn't rely on locale-specific output of commands to accomplish something as this breaks fairly easily. Especially when you want to run batch files on other computers than your own (but even in that case you can run into problems). To count files you can iterate over the files and simply count how many you encounter. The `for` statement can iterate over files in the following way:

```
set num=0
for %%f in (%root%\*) do set /a num+=1
```

Note that I'm assuming there that `%root%` is the directory whose files you are interested in. Although you earlier used `%root%`. If you're lucky, `%root%` is just `root`, otherwise your code never had a chance of working correctly.

Since you apparently want to subtract 5 for some files that are not part of what you need, you can do

```
set /a num-=5
```

afterwards. Another option, if the files you're interested in share a common trait, would be to restrict the pattern to that, e.g.

```
for %%f in (%root%\*.tif) do set /a num+=1
```

so that you don't need to subtract something from the final number.

#### 5. `for` variables are single-letter only.

The biggest one here, probably, which was pointed out by [STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779533/batch-file-for-loop/6779802#6779802) already: The variables used in `for` statements are special. They are not environment variables and they are only single-letter. The code therefore must read

```
for /l %%i in ...
```

#### 6. `for` variables must be prefixed by *two* percent signs in batch files.

On the command line a `for` statement like

```
for /l %x in (1,1,5) do @echo %x
```

is just fine, but in batch files the parser will stumble over that, probably expecting an argument to the program (which are `%1`, `%2`, etc.). As the documentation to `for` already states, inside of batch files the variables need to use two `%`:

```
for /l %%x in (1,1,5) do @echo %%x
```

This in turn will break down when used directly on the command line. [TANSTAAFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TANSTAAFL).

However, this does not hold true for environment variables. No doubling of percent signs there (see also below).

Also note that you have another error in the batch in the second-to-last line where you use `idx` like an environment variable, even though you try using it as a `for` variable elsewhere:

```
%root%\%img%__%idx%.tif
```

should read

```
%root%\%img%__%%i.tif
```

#### 7. Environment variables must be *surrounded* by `%`.

The line

```
for /l %i in (0, 1, num) do ...
```

will never work and probably complain about `num` being unexpected. To get the value of an environment variable you need to surround it with percent signs:

```
for /l %%i in (0, 1, %num%) do ...
```

otherwise it's just a string.

In a similar vein this also holds for the final `echo`. `%%i` is a `for` variable, therefore only a prefix, but `num` is an environment variable so it need to be surrounded by `%`:

```
echo blurDetection %%i of %num%
```

It can be confusing at times, but luckily we didn't yet look into delayed expansion :-).

And a final one, though minor:

#### 8. Always quote file names.

In your case the whole batch will break down as soon as `%root%` contains a path with spaces. This starts in the second line where you look for a directory existing. Make that more robust by enclosing the path in spaces:

```
if not exist "%root%\output" mkdir output
```

Same with the invocations inside the loop:

```
"%root%\blurDetection.exe" "%root%\%img%__%%i.tif" "%root%\output"
```

You don't break anything when there are no spaces in the file name, but if there are it just works as expected.

---

Now that we got that out of the way, we can look at how your batch looks now:

```
echo Starting blur detection ...
if not exist "%root%\output" mkdir "%root%\output%"
set num=0
for %%f in (%root%\*.tif) do set /a num+=1
for /l %%i in (0, 1, %num%) do (
  "%root%\blurDetection.exe" "%root%\%img%__%%i.tif" "%root%\output"
  echo blurDetection %%i of %num%
)
```

This should at least work and is probably a fairly faithful rendition of what you thought of, which I'd summarize as:

1. Create output directory if it doesn't yet exist
2. Find the number of images to process (which are named sequentially)
3. Process them and print status output.

But we are not done yet. As you noticed in above explanations, `for` can already iterate over files. With step 2 and 3 we are iterating over the set of images twice which isn't exactly needed. All it takes is a single loop and some adaptions:

```
for %%f in (%root%\%img%__*.tif) do "%root%\blurDetection.exe" "%%f" "%root%\output"
```

But now we're missing the status output. And the files no longer are processed in order (which may or may not be a problem; I'm assuming here it isn't). If you don't desperately need a “Processed file  of ” message, then the following would do:

```
for %%f in (%root%\%img%__*.tif) do (
  "%root%\blurDetection.exe" "%%f" "%root%\output"
  echo blurDetection %%~nf
)
```

which just outputs the last file name processed, but that will still process images in the order of `1`, `10`, `11`, ..., `19`, `2`, `20` ... so the number very likely does not accurately resemble progress. If you need a counter, then you need the loop from earlier again which counts the files. I think I leave this now as it is.

A few things I found curious:

- Neither `root` nor `img` are defined anywhere. I'm guessing this is just a snippet from a larger program, but to the reader it isn't nice to stumble over variables that have no visible initialization.
- While `%root%` is used in plenty of places, the current working directory seems to be identical (line 2, where you check for `%root%\output` existing and if not, create just `output`. Probably a `pushd` in the beginning and a `popd` in the end would be a cleaner way of handling this.
- You claim to quote a PowerShell error message, but that's a `cmd` error message. If you ran this script through PowerShell it'd die on the second line already.

Another thing, since you mentioned this should run on Server 2008 R2: PowerShell is installed there by default and if your execution policy is set appropriately, you can also do this with a PowerShell script:

```
Write-Host Starting blur detection ...
if (!(Test-Path $root\output)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory $root\output }
$files = Get-ChildItem $root\*.tif
$files | ForEach-Object { $i = 1 } {
    & "$root\blurDetection.exe" $_ $root\output
    Write-Host blurDetection ($i++) of ($files.Count)
}
```

Comment: as I pointed out before, it's `%%i`, not `%i`. Otherwise your first point is cosmetic, not syntactic. 2 and 8 are good points, the rest, I believe I mentioned. +1 from me.

Comment: Eek, did I make a mistake somewhere regarding `%i`? Can't find it right now. In any case, I wasn't quite sure about the order of the hints as the original mistakes were quite intertwined. While the first point might be cosmetic it's something that works different than they expect. This post was supposed to be a bit supplemental to yours, as yours already solved their problem (judging from the accepted answer) – this was intended as a learning resource if they're willing to.

Comment: yep, I quite liked it. But I don't have more than one upvote :'(

Comment: Nah, nevermind. As if batch file answers would ever yield a reasonable amount of upvotes ;-)